# Flutter FutureBuilder gets constantly called

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I'm experiencing interesting behavior. I have a FutureBuilder in Stateful widget. If I return FutureBuilder alone, everything is ok. My API gets called only once.
However, if I put extra logic, and make a choice between two widgets - I can see in chrome my API gets called tens of times. I know that `build` method executes at any time, but how does that extra logic completely breaks Future's behavior?

Here is example of api calling once.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(..);
}
```

Here is example of api being called multiple times if `someBooleanFlag` is `false`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(someBooleanFlag){
      return Text('Hello World');
    }
    else{
    return FutureBuilder(..);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Even if your code is working in the first place, you are not doing it correctly. As stated in the official documentation of [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html),

> The `future` must be obtained earlier, because if the `future` is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the `FutureBuilder`'s parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Following are the correct ways of doing it. Use either of them:

- Lazily initializing your `Future`.

  ```dart
  // Create a late instance variable and assign your `Future` to it. 
  late final Future myFuture = getFuture();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: myFuture, // Use that variable here.
      builder: (context, snapshot) {...},
    );
  }
  ```
- Initializing your `Future` in `initState`:

  ```dart
  // Create an instance variable.
  late final Future myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Assign that variable your Future.
    myFuture = getFuture();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: myFuture, // Use that variable here.
      builder: (context, snapshot) {},
    );
  }
  ```

Comment: I had this in my code, but also surrounded by ```if``` statement. However, today it seems working. Very weird. I need to spend more time in understanding this. Thank you!

Comment: if getFuture() has parameters like `getFuture(id, param)` that id and param in initialized in build method, how could you called in `initState()`? @zeromaro

Comment: Please see my answer. The above answer isn't wrong but it isn't right. It doesn't explain what you did wrong. It just shows you a way of making your code work which is not a good way to use stack overflow. You just left the parenthesis in. Let flutter decide when to call the future you are passing in.

Comment: @PatrickKelly No worries, we all make mistakes, now would you mind deleting your comment and downvote?

Comment: I had a listview builder returning from my futurebuilder with CheckboxListTile. When list item is checked, I have to call setState to show that it's been selected. This caused my FutureBuilder to fire again and again. This solved that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad We don't really need a late and a nullable(?) for the future declaration. Either one would do.

Comment: @user1613360 Yes, correct. I updated the code to only use `late`.

Answer (score 11):

Use [AsyncMemoizer](https://pub.dev/packages/async/versions)
A class for running an asynchronous function exactly once and caching its result.

```
 AsyncMemoizer _memoizer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (someBooleanFlag) {
         return Text('Hello World');
    } else {
      return FutureBuilder(
      future: _fetchData(),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
     );
    }
  }

  _fetchData() async {
    return this._memoizer.runOnce(() async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
      return 'DATA';
    });
  }
```

**Future Method:**

```
 _fetchData() async {
    return this._memoizer.runOnce(() async {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
      return 'REMOTE DATA';
    });
  }
```

This `memoizer` does exactly what we want! It takes an asynchronous function, calls it the first time it is called and caches its result. For all subsequent calls to the function, the `memoizer` returns the same previously calculated future.

Comment: Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUid() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    var uid = userRef.doc(firebaseUser.uid).get();
    return uid;
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
class QuizScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuizScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuizScreenState createState() => _QuizScreenState();
}

class _QuizScreenState extends State<QuizScreen> {
  static int count = 0;  

  initFunction() async {
    if (count > 0) return;
    else "your async function"
    count++;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    count = 0;
  }

 

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    count = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: initFunction(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return SafeArea(
              child: InfiniteCarousel.builder(
                center: true,
-
-
-
```