# FutureBuilder reloading whenever the BottomNavigationBarItem is changed

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `FutureBuilder` on a screen with `BottomNavigationBar`. But whenever I click on a different tab and come back, `FutureBuilder` reloads everything again. I'm already using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, I'm having trouble saving **getLessons()** so I don't have to load it again. Can someone help me?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Lesson>>(
        future: getLessons(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        });
  }
```

This is my getLessons():

```
  Future<List<Lesson>> getLessons() async {
    String url = "...";
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    (...)
    return lessons;
  }
```

How can I maintain the state so as not to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was calling the screens without using `PageView`. I started the 4 screens outside the `build()` and called them all within a `PageView`, now it works.

```
body: PageView(
    controller: _pageController,
    onPageChanged: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _index = index;
      });
    },
    children: [_container1, _container2, _container3, _container4],
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create instance variable
Future myFuture;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // assign this variable your Future
  myFuture = getLessons();
}


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Lesson>>(
        future: future, // use your future here
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        });
  }
```

Credit to [CopsOnRoad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57793517/12483095)

Comment: I tried this, but it always returns the connection status "None". Future does not update the status after it is loaded. If I use "getLessons()" directly, it works normally

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the PageView with PreloadPageView, the FutureBuilders will not be called again

just install `preload_page_view` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view)