# Using FutureBuilder inside Build method

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I am using `FutureBuilder` inside my `Build` method and the `FutureBuilder` keeps firing up again and again. I only want to call `FutureBuilder` once until my `future` is loaded and then call another function as soon as it is done. This is my `Build` function -

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: parsings(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return LoadingState(context);
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return new Text(
                  'Error in snapshot: \n${snapshot.error}');
            else {
              return func1();
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

As i said, my `Build` function keeps on building again and again.

Before this, i was using my `future` inside `initState` but because of that, my actual page that i wanted to return gave null values all over until the API was called. I dont want to see null values at all so i wanted to use `FutureBuilder` and display `LoadingState()` until the API was called and then show my page which has all the called values and doesnt show `null` values. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: The detailed issue i am facing is as the `build` function is being called again and again, i am seeing my `LoadingState()` again and again, that is, `LoadingState()` is appearing and then `func1()` is appearing then again, `LoadingState()`, then `func1()` and so on. this process does not stop at all. Also, i do not want to use `parsings()` in initState because on doing so, before the API is called, the `func1()` shows null values in my data and as soon as it is called, the build function changes its values to the values called from API. I don't want to see it like that which is why i wanted to use `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: Looks like you want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249578/how-to-deal-with-unwanted-widget-build

Comment: @RémiRousselet I saw that but my widget seems to be changing all the time so that solution didnt work for me, instead i put parsings() in a Future variable and awaited for it and in the future property of FutureBuilder put that Future variable, it seemed to do the job, idk how.

Comment: @Uni didnt work :(

Comment: @KushagraSrivastava Here is the solution to that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793479/flutter-futurebuilder-gets-constantly-called