# GetMaterialApp home widget is being called multiple times

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-material

I'm using `GetMaterialApp` i.e. `GetX` stage management.

The `home` widget is a `FutureBuilder` that checks user login and shows screens accordingly.

In the `builder` of the `FutureBuilder` I added a print statement and when I run the app it's being printed more than one time.

Is this fine or do I need to make some changes such that it's called only once?

Is this the behaviour of `FutureBuilder` or `GetMaterialApp`?

Below is my `home` widget code

```
home: FutureBuilder(
        future: isUserLoggedIn(),
        builder: (c, r) {
          print("LOOK");
          print(r.data);
          bool isLoggedIn = r.data == null ? false : r.data as bool;

          if (isLoggedIn) {
            return const DashboardScreen();
          }
          return const LoginScreen();
        },
      ),
```

Following is the output printed

```
I/flutter (29328): LOOK
I/flutter (29328): null
[GETX] Instance "ImageFetcher" has been created
I/flutter (29328): LOOK
I/flutter (29328): true
I/flutter (29328): LOOK
I/flutter (29328): true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is the behavior of FutureBuilder, you can see some references of this here:

[Flutter FutureBuilder gets constantly called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793479/flutter-futurebuilder-gets-constantly-called)

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

it is not related to GetX