# Why FutureBuilder re-build every time?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm working with FutureBuilder and I initialize _future in `InitState` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793479/flutter-futurebuilder-gets-constantly-called).
Despite this, `FutureBuilder` re-build itself every time I switch page with the `BottomNavigationBar`.

Code Sample:

```dart
class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

  late final Future<List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>> _futureSerieA;



  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    _futureSerieA = getScheduled("Serie A");

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [


            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(

                  border: Border(

                    bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)
                  )
                ),
                child: Theme(
                  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: _futureSerieA,
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {

                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        List<String> scheduled = [];

                        for (var DOC in snapshot.data!) {
                          scheduled.add(DOC.id);
                        }
                        return ...
```

How could I disable FutureBuilder re-build when browsing between pages of BottomNavigationBar?

BottomNavBar:

```dart
class _LoggedHandleState extends State<LoggedHandle> {

 
  );
  double height = AppBar().preferredSize.height;

  int _selectedPage = 1;
  final _pageOptions = [
    const BetView(),
    const HomeView(),
    const UserView()
  ];




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      ...
      ),
    

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white60,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.receipt),
              label: 'Schedina',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              label: 'Account',
            ),
          ]),

      body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
    );
  }

 
}
```

Comment: I prefer using nullable data on `StatefulWidget`

Comment: Is this affecting `FutureBuilder` behaviour?

Comment: Can you provide a simplified widget that will reproduce the same error

Comment: It's very complex, the future `getScheduled` works with FirebaseAuth and Firestore... I can attach the code of the BottomNavigationBar, I think the problem is that `InitState` is called each time I change the page

Comment: You can create a dummy future that will reproduce the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When browsing between pages of bottom navigation bar, your state is not maintained. This behaviour causes the widget to rebuild every time.

You can use Indexed Stack https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html

```
  @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                current_tab = index;
              });
            },
            currentIndex: current_tab,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                ...
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                ...
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: IndexedStack(
            children: <Widget>[
              PageOne(),
              PageTwo(),
            ],
            index: current_tab,
          ),
        );
      }
```

Although this is the best solution, it will load all your widgets once the IndexedStack is loaded.
I found a Lazy Loading Indexed Stack util to load your widgets when and only the first time they are created https://github.com/okaryo/lazy_load_indexed_stack

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to test this solution. Just I did'nt understand very well the last part of your answer: why should I need lazy_load_indexed_stack?

Comment: Because all of your widgets are going to be built at the same time when IndexedStack is placed in the widget tree, maybe this is not your case but if you have a lot of widgets or your widgets are heavy, they will be loaded at the same time and you may experience performance issues.

Comment: Correctly tested, thank you Fernando